# Objective-C SSL issue: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9847)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl

We have a custom mobile application using a third party framework for authentication. The framework will connect to a web based server running on tomcat. This server is protected by a TSL 1.2 certificate. If I connect without SSL the connection is successful. The error message I receive is below.

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9847)
```

I assume this error message means it is resolving to the server, but is unable to complete SSL handshake.

In the **Info.plist** I have configured the following.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>yoursite.here.com</key>
            <dict>
                <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to allow insecure HTTP requests-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

In addition to this I attempted to bypass the new IOS standard for certs by replacing the above snippet with. However the outcome was the same

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Connect to anything (this is probably BAD)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

The certificate is self-signed and does not require interaction when the user accesses via `MicroStrategy` Web.

Comment: I also got "CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)" error too. Did you find out any solution yet?

Comment: Hi I am getting this error too. And tried this solution but did not get any solution so can you suggest me some another ways.

Comment: Hi. I get this error so did you have any solution?? Please suggest to me.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the incorrect port for SSL, needed to use 443.